# Remove slice increment in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slice, increment

I have a list, each list element has class `.card-deck` I have used the jQuery function slice to only show 6 from my list until the user clicks the button load more `<button class="show-more w-100">Load more</button>` this works and increments 3 more each click, this is what im after so that's working.

What I need is a button to decrement 3 as well, I have tried to simply change my +3 to -3 however this is not working.

Is there a way to modify my code to get this working ?
Also for some reason I need to click the button twice to get it to work the first click.. is there a way to have it work on the first click?

**My code**

```
if ($('.card-deck').length > 6) {
    $('.card-deck').hide();
    $('.card-deck').slice(0,6).show();
}
let clicks = +3;
$('.show-more').on('click', function() {
    clicks = clicks+3;
    $('.card-deck').slice(0,clicks).fadeIn();
});

$('.show-less').on('click', function() {
    clicks = clicks-3;
    $('.card-deck').slice(0,clicks).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: well you need to hide the ones that are shown

Comment: As comment above, replace your less fadeIn with: `$('.card-deck').slice(clicks,clicks+3).fadeOut()`  (there are other ways, this just to show where/how)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hide the ones that were shown.

```js
const cards = $('.card-deck')
let clicks = 3;
let stepSize = 3

if (cards.length > 3) {
  cards.hide();
  cards.slice(0, 3).show();
}
$('.show-more').on('click', function() {
  clicks = clicks + stepSize;
  if (clicks > cards.length) {
    clicks = cards.length
  }
  cards.slice(0, clicks).fadeIn();
});

$('.show-less').on('click', function() {
  clicks = clicks - stepSize;
  if (clicks < 0) {
    clicks = 0
  }
  cards.slice(clicks, cards.length).fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="card-deck">1</li>
  <li class="card-deck">2</li>
  <li class="card-deck">3</li>
  <li class="card-deck">4</li>
  <li class="card-deck">5</li>
  <li class="card-deck">6</li>
  <li class="card-deck">7</li>
  <li class="card-deck">8</li>
  <li class="card-deck">9</li>
  <li class="card-deck">10</li>
  <li class="card-deck">11</li>
  <li class="card-deck">12</li>
</ul>

<button class="show-more">+</button>
<button class="show-less">-</button>
```